# How to change display style in Coq IDE to match Coqtop?

Tags: coq, coqide

The implication connective is printed as lambda expression in my `coqide` (OS X El Capitan). is that the expected behavior? I would prefer to see them printed as in `coqtop`. I couldn't find the option/command line option to change the display style.

[image: coqtop and coqide]

Comment: Check the `View -> Display notations` menu entry.

Comment: thank you! i had it checked when i took the screenshots but somehow toggling it fixes it.

Comment: You should respond unsing the Answer box ;)

Comment: @Vinz All right. Done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Make sure the *View → Display notations* menu entry is checked in CoqIDE.

### Long answer

Coq by default pretty-prints stuff using notations.

> A *notation* is a symbolic abbreviation denoting some term or term pattern.

The notation for `->` is defined in [Coq.Init.Logic](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html):

> `Notation "A -> B" := (forall (_ : A), B) : type_scope.`

At this point we can conclude that Coq for some reason is unfolding notations for you.

In 'coqtop' (a toplevel, or REPL for Coq) or in [ProofGeneral](https://proofgeneral.github.io) you can use the Vernacular commands

```
Set Printing Notations.
```

and

```
Unset Printing Notations.
```

in your proof scripts to control the output (one can read `Set` / `Unset` in the commands above as `Use` / `Do not use`).

Unfortunately, those do not work in CoqIDE v8.5: if you try it, you'll get the following error message:

> This will not work. Use CoqIDE display menu instead

I guess the only reasonable option we have is to check the *View → Display notations* menu entry.